# Use a variable as an attribute name

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to get the attributes in a certain order so I'm using a loop on a specific set of names. I want to do something like @$attribute or something like @. but just using . is giving me the name itself, not the value of the attribute which is what I want.

Basically instead of saying "title" and "artist" for each row, I want the actual title and artist.

hello.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <r title="Empire Burlesque" artist="Bob Dylan" />
  <r title="Hide your heart" artist="Bonnie Tyler" />
  <r title="Greatest Hits" artist="Dolly Parton" />
</results>
```

hello.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template name="boxNames"> <!-- not used as template -->
  <name>title</name>
  <name>artist</name>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="boxNames" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name='boxNames']/name" />
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <xsl:for-each select="$boxNames">
      <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="." /></th>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="results/r">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="$boxNames">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left">title</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">artist</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>artist</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>artist</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>artist</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>Execution time: 88.941623ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't simply hardcode the order of the columns you want into the stylesheet itself, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/results">
    <html> 
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- header -->
                <tr>
                    <th>title</th>
                    <th>artist</th>
                </tr>
                <!-- body -->
                <xsl:for-each select="r">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@artist"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if you really want to enumerate the column names in a separate list, try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="columns">
    <name>title</name>
    <name>artist</name>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="column-names" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='columns']/name" />

<xsl:template match="/results">
    <html> 
        <body>
            <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <!-- header -->
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$column-names">
                        <th>
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </th>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
                <!-- body -->
                <xsl:for-each select="r">
                    <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$column-names">
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$row/@*[name()=current()]"/>
                            </td>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```